# MobaXterm console and Rscript

Tags: r, terminal, rscript

I recently started using MobaXterm console and I would like to execute Rscripts in it. I read that I should include # !usr/bin... code in my R script, but this doesnt work, as Moba still doesn't recognize Rscript command.
I also tried to move Rscript.exe in the directory where the R script is, but it doesn't work either.

I.e. Rscript my_code.R
The code is straightforward :print("Hello"), and doesn't send in error when ran in Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

To make Rscript work from Windows shell in Windows 10:

-Right click on lower right part screen (windows legend) to open the menu
-Click on System
-Click on Associate Parameters / System information (right part of screen)
-Click on System advanced parameters
-Click on Advanced / Environmental variables
-In the lower window (system variables) click on "Path" and edit
-Add the location of Rscript.exe (i.e. C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4\bin)

To test whether it works:

-Right click on lower right part screen (windows legend) to open the menu
-Windows PowerShell
-Type Rscript
-Text should come out

Comment: To use this in Moba: 
https://superuser.com/questions/929711/use-windows-path-variable-in-mobaxterm